# Marklogic - convert xml to csv

Tags: marklogic

Does Marklogic has a function to convert xml to csv similar to json:transform-to-json.   I can convert to json format but not sure how to transform from xml to csv format and save to disk.

```
let $uris := cts:uris((),
                  (),
                  cts:and-query((
                          cts:collection-query("/citation"),
                          cts:field-range-query("sdt","<","2017-10-01"),
                          cts:field-range-query("edt",">","2016-09-30"),
                          cts:or-query(cts:field-range-query("fy","=",2017)),
                          cts:not-query(cts:field-word-query("dc","a","case-insensitive"))
                  ))

                 )
for $uri in $uris

let $doc := fn:doc($uri)

let $copymeta := <meta:Metadata> 
                   {$doc//meta:Metadata/*}
            </meta:Metadata> 

let $newdoc := <mdr:record>
                    { $copymeta }


             </mdr:record>
(: get information for each element:)
let $metadata := $newdoc/meta:Metadata

let $Title := ($metadata/meta:Title)
let $Title :=fn:string-join($Title,",")
let $DateOfSummary:= ($metadata/meta:DateOfSummary)
let $DateOfSummary:=fn:string-join($DateOfSummary,",")
let $quote:=
   for $value in($Title,$DateOfSummary)
      return fn:concat("&#34;",$value,"&#34;")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a transform in Server-Side JavaScript, XQuery, or XSLT that iterates over the XML documents, projecting the CSV rows as strings.

On MarkLogic 9, as an alternative, you can write a TDE template that projects the CSV rows from the XML documents,

http://docs.marklogic.com/tde:node-data-extract

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/creating-template-views

and set the output method to "sparql-results-csv" before returning the projected rows to the client:

http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:set-response-output-method

Based on the output method, the appserver should serialize the rows as CSV.

If you need to extract CSV rows from documents based on a query, you can use the TDE to index the documents and make the request to the /v1/rows endpoint:

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/client/row-management

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Note though that changing your TDE templates requires reindexing. Using TDE to project rows out of documents is faster than iterating over documents and doing the same thing because it leverages indexes, however because it leverages indexes, changing it requires reindexing.